# Restructure line fields in a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Am a newbie to coding but would like to use either awk, sed or bash to solve this problem.
I have a file "input.txt" that looks like this:

```
Otu13  k__Bacteria;p__Firmicutes;c__Bacilli;o__Lactobacillales;f__Streptococcaceae;g__Streptococcus        0.998
Otu24  k__Bacteria;p__Candidatus_Saccharibacteria;g__Saccharibacteria_genera_incertae_sedis; 1.000;; 
Otu59  k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidetes;c__Bacteroidia;o__Bacteroidales;f__Prevotellaceae;g__Alloprevotella        0.991
Otu41  k__Bacteria;p__Bacteroidetes;g__Alloprevotella        0.998
```

Firstly, I would like to drop the last column with numbers, then for the rest of the fields in each line, write them out depending on their prefix (k__, p__, o__, f__, g__).

The values after the prefixes should be printed out in a similar order as in parenthesis such that if one of the prefix in the sequences order is missing e.g. line 2 and 4, then they are replaced with blank. In the end I should have 7 fields.

My desired output is something like this:

```
Otu13; Bacteria; Firmicutes; Bacilli; Lactobacillales; Streptococcaceae; Streptococcus
Otu24; Bacteria; Candidatus_Saccharibacteria; ; ; ;Saccharibacteria_genera_incertae_sedis
Otu59; Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Prevotellaceae;Alloprevotella
Otu41; Bacteria;Bacteroidetes; ; ; ; Alloprevotella
```

Will greatly appreciate your assistance.

Comment: What about the `c__` fields? Why do you want the first `;` to have a space after it? What's the logic that causes some output fields to have a leading space while others don't?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear how/why you'd get the output you show from the input you posted and the description of your requirements but I think this is what you really want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { n=split("k p c o f g",order); FS="[ ;]+|__"; OFS=";" }
{
    sub(/[0-9.;[:space:]]+$/,"")
    delete f
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) {
        f[$i] = $(i+1)
    }
    printf "%s%s", $1, OFS
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", f[order[i]], (i<n ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Otu13;Bacteria;Firmicutes;Bacilli;Lactobacillales;Streptococcaceae;Streptococcus
Otu24;Bacteria;Candidatus_Saccharibacteria;;;;Saccharibacteria_genera_incertae_sedis
Otu59;Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;Bacteroidia;Bacteroidales;Prevotellaceae;Alloprevotella
Otu41;Bacteria;Bacteroidetes;;;;Alloprevotella
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to include the c__ field. The input file comes from another software with spaces, but the desired output doesn't need to have spaces after the ";" so your code does exactly what is needed. Many thanks Ed! Could you kindly give me an explanation of what it does please? Thank you

Comment: I used to do this in Excel but as the output grew, it became obvious I need to learn better and less error prone ways.

Comment: It creates an array named `order[]` of the key values (p, c, etc.) in the order you want them output. Then as it reads every line it stores the part after `__` in an array `f[]` indexed by the part before the `__` (i.e. the key value p, c, etc). Then it just loops through `order[1->n]` to get the key value p, c, etc. at that index and prints the value of `f[]` indexed by that p, c, etc.